# Which one is correct to use, first-person form or third person form?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-person, third-person

In the below sentence, should "implement" need to be in a first person form or third person form as it is now?

> > This Regulation is set up with a view to ensure that subject people comply with ruleA and ruleB, and properly implements their responsible works.

Comment: Note that *implements* and *comply* are **both** third-person forms, but one is singular and the other plural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If *implements* refers to the Regulation, it must be singular. If it refers to *subject people* then it should ideally be plural to agree with *comply*.

The sentence could be ambiguous, but the number of the verb indicates what is doing the implementing. It is the verb which disambiguates.

> This Regulation is set up with a view to ensure that subject people comply with Rule A and Rule B, and [the Regulation] properly implements [the people's] responsible works.